# Approached by recruiter for job I was going to apply for directly

Tags: software-industry, recruitment

Having found myself between jobs unexpectedly, I have started my job hunt again. I came across a job with a particular company that I have wanted to work for for a while being advertised on their website, so decided to save it for later. Earlier today, I was approached by a recruiter via email recruiting for the same position.

I will be applying for this position either way, but I have no idea if it would be better for me to approach the company directly or to approach them through the recruiter. Can anyone lend any guidance on this?

Answer (score 6):

I would approach the company directly. The recruiter will just add a layer of complexity to the process.

Also consider that it's cheaper for the company to hire you as they won't be paying the agency a finder's fee.  If it comes down to you and another candidate,  that could well tip things in your favour.

Comment: yes, cut out the middleman and expense